# Struct dereference in masm

Tags: assembly, struct, x86, masm, masm32

I'm experimenting with using masm32 to code in x86 assembly. I'm interfacing with some WinAPI calls, and I need to access structs via pointers.

Here is my basic code:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT, C
OPTION CASEMAP:NONE
.STACK

obj STRUCT
  field      DWORD       ?
obj ENDS

objPtr TYPEDEF PTR obj

.CODE

main PROC
  LOCAL inst : objPtr

; Assume inst is assigned to something (result of function call eg)


main ENDP

END main
```

So I've got a pointer to a struct, the pointer is given to me as the result of a function, so assume it points to a valid struct. What I want to know is how I can reassign some of its fields. In C, I'd use the -> operator to do so, for example:

```
inst->field = 42
```

I need to do the equivalent in my Assembly code. Is it possible without having to make a local copy of the struct to access directly? Do I perhaps need to put the pointer into a register? I've attempted some research by myself but I'm having difficulty understanding the code I see, or finding specific MASM examples.

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: _"Do I perhaps need to put the pointer into a register?"_ Yes.

Comment: So there is no way to access the struct in one line as in C?

Comment: You might have noticed that many things which can be done on one line in C can't be done by one instruction in assembly :)

Comment: Indeed. So once I move the pointer into (say) ebx, how do I access the fields of the struct through that register?

Comment: `[ebx+<offset>]` to access some memory around pointer  (not sure if `[ebx+field]` doesn't actually produce the correct `[ebx]` with removed +0 (as `field` in your example `struct` is at offset 0) in MASM ... I'm not a big fan of bending assembly into somewhat higher language with macros and structs etc... my asm sources tend to define structs by my own EQU constants (not using `STRUCT` directive at all, as I was not sure how it compiles to machine code, while I had clear vision what the machine code should be).

Comment: It was my understanding in that case that "offset" had to be a number. Can it be the field name too? There'd have to be a way for the Assembler to tell which type of struct it was pointing to, in order to calculate the address.

Comment: According to google you can do stuff like `ASSUME eax: PTR obj;  mov [eax].field, 42`. Also, it may be worth a try to do `mov inst.field, 42` your assembler may generate some magical working code for that.

Comment: About calculating address... the struct fields are sort of offsets, so there's no calculation needed, and tracking "type" of value/ptr is next to impossible in assembly. The MASM tries hard, but it felt always weird to me, I prefer rather clean asm code so I can understand what I read just from disassembly and find it in source in almost the same form, so I don't have to think about MASM quirks and how it compiles certain things. I mean, if I want somewhat logical high level language, C++ is my first choice. If I want for whatever weird reason some exact machine code, I prefer asm.

Comment: Jester's example with the ASSUME keyword has worked for me. Many thanks to you both for the advice!